# Invert Colors in a Jekyll Site

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

I am using a Jekyll theme to power my blog, https://github.com/heiswayi/the-plain.

The theme is all white, I just want to invert the color i.e. white becomes black and black becomes white identical to what this chrome extension looks like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en (Dark Reader) does.

I searched the web, but I could not find any answer specific to jekyll sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the color of this theme you will have to tweak the *css* file, in this case is located at https://github.com/heiswayi/the-plain/blob/master/_sass/main.scss so you can copy `_sass/main.scss` to your jekyll installation and change every color / background color.